# Export data Telerik grid

Tags: telerik-grid, radgrid

I'm using RadGrid from Telerik (RadGrid.Net2 (I know I should upgrade to a newer version, but that is not an option here..)). One of it's features is to export data to excel. With  `grid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();` an excel file is created with filtered and sorted data from the grid (all pages). How can i grab this data?

```
grd.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
grd.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
grd.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
```

I want to grab the same data as Telerik is writing to excel but can't figure out how to do this..

`grd.MasterTableView.GetExportDataAsDataTable()` would be perfect ;)

Comment: What is the issue w/ the data in grd.DataSource ?

Comment: tha DataSource property will give you the original data. Not sorted or  filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could be able to do this by inspecting the code in ExportToExcel, and hooking on some logic to the MasterTableView, but I really don't think there are any 'standard' way of doing this..